# Swift 3 - append an array as 1 item into another array

Tags: arrays, swift

while this link: [Add an element to an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift)
shows how to add an item to an array, my question is about adding an array as an item to another array.

I did not find any similar question - I have these arrays:

`[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`

I want to append the first array to the other one as a whole, so I get this result:

```
[4,5,6,[1,2,3]]
```

Please note that this is *NOT* expected result:

```
[4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Start with defining your array types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an element to an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this case, the container array should be of type `[Any]` to let it contains *ints* and *array of ints*.

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3] // by default, it should be of type [Int]
let arr2:[Any] = [4,5,6,arr1]

print(arr2) // [4, 5, 6, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Note that Swift is strongly typed, by default, array *must* be an array of ints, -unlike Objective-C- array cannot contains mix of data types.

That's why you should [Any](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) type:

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function
>   types.

Note that:

> Use Any and AnyObject only when you explicitly need the behavior and
>   capabilities they provide. *It is always better to be specific about*
>   *the types you expect to work with in your code.*

---

**Accessing Elements:**

By default, accessing elements from `[Any]` array should be of type of `Any`, for example:

```
let numberOne = arr2[0] // type of Any
let myArray = arr2[3] // type of Any
```

For getting the desired data type, you should *cast* it using `as?` operator with *optional binding*, as follows:

```
if let oneInt = arr2[0] as? Int {
    print("one is an Int and it equals to: \(oneInt)")
} else {
    print("one is NOT ad Int")
}
// one is an Int and it equals to: 4

if let oneString = arr2[0] as? String {
    print("one is an Int and it equals to: \(oneString)")
} else {
    print("one is NOT ad Int")
}
// one is NOT ad Int
```

*Remark*: using `as!` operator will cause the application to crash if the type does not matched.

```
let oneInt = arr2[0] as! Int // works fine
let oneString = arr2[0] as! String // CRASH!
```

For more information about `as` operators you might want to check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637974/whats-the-difference-between-as-as-and-as) and the [Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a: [Any] = [1,2,3]
var b: [Int] = [3,4,5]
a.append(b) // [1, 2, 3, [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayOne = [1,2,3]
var arrayTwo = [4,5,6]
```

if you want result as : [4,5,6,[1,2,3]]

```
arrayTwo.append(arrayOne)
```

above code will convert arrayOne as a single element and add it to the end of arrayTwo.

if you want result as : [4,5,6,1,2,3] then,

```
arrayTwo.append(contentsOf: arrayOne)
```

above code will add all the elements of arrayOne at the end of arrayTwo.

Thanks.