# What is difference between as? and as! in swift

Tags: swift

Does the as! unwrap what ever is before it like

```
var a = value as! Double
```

the a is not an optional

where

```
var a = value as? Double
```

the a is optional Double?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637974/whats-the-difference-between-as-as-and-as

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388434/3141234

Answer (score 4):

`as?` produces an optional value, which is either the value if it can be cast to the specified type, or `nil` if it can't.

`as!` doesn't produce an optional, it just produces a value of the specified type, and if the cast fails, it aborts the program. Saying `foo as! SomeType` is basically the same thing as saying `(foo as? SomeType)!` (except you get a better error message).

You should only ever use `as!` if you're 100% certain the cast will succeed (because if you're wrong, the whole program aborts).