# Array of struct cannot be counted or iterated through in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

In **Swift 4** I created struct `Vybe`, an array of `Vybe`, and a dictionary.

```
struct Vybe {
        let monthDay: String
        let category: String
        let description: String
    }
var listVybe:[Vybe] = []
var dictVybe = [AnyHashable:Any]()
```

Then grouped it by a date string.

`self.dictVybe = Dictionary(grouping: self.listVybe) { $0.monthDay }`

This gave me the structs grouped into an array successfully. But, I am unable to count or iterate through this array. When attempting a for loop I get an error: `Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'`. How can I loop or count this group of Array?

Some debugging PRINT:

```
 print("\(type(of: self.dictVybe["Monday, Jul 16"]!)) ,\(#function)")
 print((self.dictVybe["Monday, Jul 16"]))
```

OUTPUT:

> Array< Vybe> ,fetchData()
>
> Optional([VybrantApp.activityTask.Vybe(monthDay: "Monday, Jul 16", category: "Elated", description: "good desc"),
>   VybrantApp.activityTask.Vybe(monthDay: "Monday, Jul 16", category:
>   "Happy", description: "better desc"),
>   VybrantApp.activityTask.Vybe(monthDay: "Monday, Jul 16", category:
>   "Anxiety", description: "great desc")])

Comment: Change your `dictVybe` to `var dictVybe = [String: [Vybe]]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
( dictVybe[ "Monday, Jul 16" ] as! [ Vybe ] ).count
```

does the thing.

Comment: What does `as! [ Vybe ]` do here? Set it to an array of struct?

Comment: dictVybe's value is type of [ Vibe ] because you have created by Dictionary(grouping: self.listVybe) { $0.monthDay }, so you can cast the value to the type of [ Vibe ] which is countable and iteratable. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637974/whats-the-difference-between-as-as-and-as